# ColdFusion 8 query blowing up

Tags: sql, t-sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Have a slight issue. I'm trying to create an XML feed that searches a database based on first name, last name, etc. The response I'd like to get is the typical first, last, DOB etc. That search I have running fine. However I'm trying to add another function to it.

For each individual person returned, I would like to return extra fields for others at the same address. I hijacked code from another xml feed that works, doing somewhat the same thing, but it just won't work for this feed. I embedded some of the code to run that addition. It basically runs by taking the address for each individual returned and runs the address via stored procedure to obtain others at each particular person. But its blowing sky high and cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Below is the code giving me issues. I guess its a query of queries. I just enclosed what would be the results where the query is generated. Also I am using CF 8.

```
<FDSResponse>

<cfoutput><ResultCount>#resultCount#</ResultCount>
<Generated>#dateFormat(now(),"mm/dd/yyyy")# #timeFormat(now(),"long")#</Generated></cfoutput>
<searchResults>
    <PeopleFinder>
        <cfoutput query="getResults">
        <Result>
            <ValidityDate>#Right(validityDate,2)#/#Left(validityDate,4)#</ValidityDate>
            <LastName>#xmlFormat(lastname)#</LastName>
            <FirstName>#xmlFormat(firstname)#</FirstName>
            <MiddleName>#xmlFormat(middlename)#</MiddleName>
            <DOB><CFIF dateOfBirth NEQ "">#trim(xmlFormat("#mid(dateOfBirth,3,2)#/#right(dateofbirth,2)#/19#left(dateofbirth,2)#"))#</CFIF></DOB>
            <Address>#xmlformat(address)#</Address>
            <City>#xmlformat(city)#</City>
            <State>#xmlFormat(state)#</State>
            <Zip>#zip#</Zip>
            <County>#xmlformat(countyName)#</County>
            <Phone>#xmlformat(phoneNumber)#</Phone>
            <personID>#ID#</personID>

            <CFQUERY datasource="PF" name="getRoomates#currentrow#" maxrows="25">
               sp_roomateSearch '#address#', '#City#', '#state#', '#left(Zip,5)#', '#var.firstname#', '#var.lastname#', '#getResults.dateofbirth#'
            </CFQUERY>

            <otherpeople>
            <address>#xmlFormat(trim(address))#</address>
            <city>#xmlFormat(trim(city))#</city>
            <state>#xmlFormat(trim(state))#</state>
            <zip>#xmlFormat(trim(zip))#</zip>
            <!---<otherPeople>
            <cfloop query="getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#">
                <person>
                <ValidityDate>#Right(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.validityDate'),2)#/#Left(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.validityDate'),4)#</ValidityDate>
                    <possibleRelative><CFIF evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.lastname') EQ var.lastname>TRUE<CFELSE>UNKNOWN</CFIF></possibleRelative>
                    <LastName>#xmlFormat(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.lastname'))#</LastName>
                    <FirstName>#xmlFormat(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.firstname'))#</FirstName>
                    <MiddleName>#xmlFormat(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.middlename'))#</MiddleName>
                    <CFSAVECONTENT variable="DOB"><CFIF evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.dateOfBirth') NEQ "">#mid(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.dateOfBirth'),3,2)#/<CFIF right(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.dateOfBirth'),2) NEQ "00">#right(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.dateOfBirth'),2)#/<CFSET dbirth = right(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.dateOfBirth'),2)><CFELSE><CFSET dbirth = "01"></CFIF>#left(evaluate('getRoomates#getOtherResults.currentrow#.dateOfBirth'),2)#</CFIF></CFSAVECONTENT>
                    <DOB>#xmlFormat(replace(DOB," ","","ALL"))#</DOB>
                </person>
            </cfloop>
            </otherPeople>
        </Result>
        </cfoutput>
    </PeopleFinder>
</searchResults>
</FDSResponse>
```

Comment: Also I should note I'd like the others at the same address nested within the <Result></Result> nodes... thx

Comment: _"But its blowing sky high and cannot for the life of me figure out why."_ - start by reading the error message. If it's not being displayed on screen, check the log files.